# Creating Runnable JAR from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I look over a lot of info on the web also look at some of the questions here, but couldn't solve my problem so I post this question. I have fairly simple project using `SWING` which compiles and run under Eclipse, but when I try to use the standard `Export->Java->Runnable Jar` leaving the default properties at the end I have a file which when I dobule-click I get this: `Could not find the main class: TableFilterDemo. Program will exit`.
Here is my project structure:

[image]

And this is the configuration I use for creating the `Runnable Jar` :

[image]

And because as far as I understand the error there is some problem with locating the `main` method I left `TableFilterDremo.java` with only the `main` method in it:

```
public class TableFilterDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CreateGUI.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By far no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the full wizard that Eclipse provides, you'll see there is a screen prompting you to select a main class.

Answer (score 0):

On the screen before the one you show in the screenshoot, you have to manually select the classes that will be included in the jar.

A good way to check they have been included is to unzip the generated jar file (for example with winzip or winrar) and check it contains all the files.